# Instantiate 50 objects of type custom with names from an NSArray

Tags: objective-c

I am unable to name/instantiate new objects within a for Loop as the for Loop moves through an array of names.  The syntax `*namesArray objectAtIndex:i]` is wrong. What syntax would allow new objects to be named/instantiated by names held in an array?  I have 50 objects to instantiate.

**myCustomObject.h:**

```
@interface myCustomObject : NSObject
@property(weak, nonatomic) NSString *birthday;

namesArray = @[ @"bob", @"tom", @"ed", @"Sue"];
birthday = @[@"11/20/86", @"5/16/82", @"01/2/81", @"10/7/87"];
for ( int i=0; i < [namesArray count]; i++ )  {
    myCutomObject *[namesArray objectAtIndex:i] = [[myCutomObject alloc] initWithBday:[birthday objectAtIndex:i]]; 
}
```

Comment: Do you have a CustomObject that has name and birthday properties? This seems like what you want. The code snippet you provided is only using the birthday array information and replacing the items in the name array. I don't think you want this; please correct me if I wrong.

Comment: First Thanks for your help.  The best way to put it is -   I have a custom object,  I want to create 50 instances.  I want each instance to have a name pulled from an array of names.    myCustomObject *bob = [[myCustomObject] alloc]    then with next iteration   myCustomObject *tom = [[myCustomObject] alloc]

Comment: Thank you Taylor.  my problem is not with the object properties, but with the naming of the object at its instantiation.  Object bob has the property birthday.  object tom has the property birthday.  etc.   the next object would be instantiated with the name ed.  object ed has the property birthday.

Comment: Okay. I think I understand. Note that the naming of you instances of MyCustomObject has no effect the object itself, it just represents how you reference the objects in code. So not sure what benefit you are trying to gain from naming your instances with the person's name. That being said, if you wanted to have an "array" of birthday's where you can use the name as a "key" to reference the birthday, you should use a dictionary. A dictionary is a set of key-value pairs. For example you could say myCustomObjectDictionary["bob"] and this would return "11/20/86". Note that each key must be unique.

Comment: That being said. I think your best choice would be to create a Person object with a name property and a birthday property. Have an initializer that would take two strings (one for the name and one for the birthday). Then you would store your person objects in an array. You could then use an NSPredicate to filter/search your array by name or birthday (or another property you add to your Person class) for the correct Person.

Comment: What are writing right now? It does not make any sense for Objective-C or are you trying to post your question in simple way?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generate new variable names at run time.

If you want to look up instances of `myCustomObject` by “name” at run time, add them to an `NSMutableDictionary` when you create them, and look them up by name when you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Great information thank you both, Rob and Taylor.  I dig your answers.  I decided to just go ahead and hand-jam in 50 lines of object instantiaters.  Here is my actual code times 50, though.

```
SchoolMascot *Rams = [[SchoolMascot alloc] init];
SchoolMascot *Bears = [[SchoolMascot alloc] init];
SchoolMascot *Lions = [[SchoolMascot alloc] init];
```

It's a football thing. The SchoolMascot object has a bunch of properties, which I did use a For Loop to load.  Wish I could have used the same loop to instantiate.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Why are you creating 50 unique variables instead of putting the objects in an appropriate collection?

Comment: Cook, Tanks, Maddy.  I appreciate your perspective.  Got it - an appropriate collection.